# In how many ways can you arrange the alphabet so that A and B are always next to one another (In either order)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Ok, so I have no idea where to begin on this question.
Do I treat A and B as one letter? 25 choose n?

Comment: Arrange all the other letters.  Then choose one of "AB" and "BA" and find a place to insert it.

Comment: So arranging the other letters would be 24!... How do I go about dealing with the AB and BA?

Comment: @Callus would it be 24! * C(2,1) ?

Comment: That will get you an arrangement of the other alphabet and an arrangement of ("A","B"), but you still need to find a spot for the ("A","B") pair

Comment: @Callus Well there are 24 letters which means 25 places to insert it. so C(25,1)?

24! * C(2,1) * C(25,1)

Comment: Numerically, yes, conceptually, I would have put $24! \cdot 2! \cdot \binom{25}{1}$.  You're finding an arrangement of $24$ letters, an independent arrangement of $2$ letters, and choosing a position between $0$ and $24$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can treat $A$ and $B$ as one letter, call it $AB$.  Order your alphabet, which now has $25$ letters (how many ways?).  Now resolve $AB$ into either $A,B$ or $B,A$, which is two choices, so multiply by $2$.

Comment: This is what I originally thought of.  So now with 25 letters...there are 25! ways to arrange them. Multiplying by the ways to arrange A & B would leave me with: 25! * 2... yes?

Comment: @user134788:  exactly

Comment: and this is identical to the above way of arranging the remaining 24, then arranging AB, and then choosing a place to insert it.  Awesome, I understand! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are many different ways to calculate this.  They all lead to the same answer (if done correctly).

Comment: @Just for reinforcements sake.... What would I do if I wanted to arrange the alphabet so that A and B AREN'T next to one another?

Comment: Having done this, I would arrange the alphabet in any way, then subtract the number of ways A and B are together.  I would probably do that even if I hadn't just done this.

Comment: Ok. So there are 26! ways to arrange the alphabet and there are 2*25! ways to get the alphabet with AB next to each other.  So 26! - (25! * 2). Cool, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.